# python: get size of buffer

Tags: python, types

I'm reading data from local and from remote (urllib2) files in a Python script.

What is the return datatype?

How can I get the size of this data? ("real" size, not the size of representation in Python, in case that differs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type is a bytestring. The length of the string is the size in bytes of the data.

Answer (score 0):

What function specifically are you asking for the return type? `urllib2.urlopen`? To get the size of an object, use `sys.getsizeof` or if it's a string, use `len(str)` to get it's size.